# selecting all duplicates

Tags: mysql

How can I update this to select all duplicates?

```
SELECT address FROM list  
GROUP BY address HAVING count(id) > 1
```

Currently, I think it just returs the addresses which are duplciated.  I want all duplicates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql INNER JOIN syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655922/mysql-inner-join-syntax)

Comment: If there are 5 duplicates will it return a row for each?

Comment: Even though not an exact duplicate, this is asking a subset of the problem asked by the other question: [MySQL INNER JOIN Syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655922/mysql-inner-join-syntax).

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  What 'duplicates' are you wanting to select?  Are you looking for specific columns to be returned?  Also, the table definition/schema may be helpful.

Comment: No - it will return one copy of the address for each duplicated address.  The GROUP BY ensures that similar values are collected together; the HAVING ensure that only repeated addresses are listed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Select * from list
where address in (
  select address from list group by address
  having count(*) > 1);
```

Look at this sample query I ran:

```
mysql> select * from flights;
+--------+-------------+
| source | destination |
+--------+-------------+
|      1 |           2 |
|      3 |           4 |
|      5 |           6 |
|      6 |           1 |
|      2 |           4 |
|      1 |           3 |
|      5 |           2 |
|      6 |           3 |
|      6 |           5 |
|      6 |           4 |
+--------+-------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from flights where source in 
       (select source from flights group by source having count(*) > 1);
+--------+-------------+
| source | destination |
+--------+-------------+
|      1 |           2 |
|      5 |           6 |
|      6 |           1 |
|      1 |           3 |
|      5 |           2 |
|      6 |           3 |
|      6 |           5 |
|      6 |           4 |
+--------+-------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: what if ther where say 3 X addresses...would I get two rows returned?..or just the first duplciate?

Comment: No you will just get one row returned... Let me add that case too in the sample query I wrote.

Comment: I am still not sure what you need. It will be great if you can add a sample table and your desired output.

Comment: they have it here...but there are like 5 answers..which one?

Comment: you have to INNER JOIN or something

Comment: Now I understand what you need, give a min to check that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4008/discussion-between-topcoder-and-chris-aaker)

Answer (score 4):

If I'm correct, you're looking for the actual rows that contain duplicates -- so that if you have three rows with the same address, you return all three rows.

Here's how to do it:

```
SELECT * FROM list
WHERE address in (
    SELECT address FROM list GROUP BY address HAVING count(id) > 1
);
```

This should generally work unless your address is a 'text' field or if your address table has more than a few thousand duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT * FROM list
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM list
    GROUP BY address HAVING count(id) > 1
);
```

Comment: Since you're grouping by address, I believe this will pull back only a single row for each address -- instead of all rows for the address. The `count(id)` in your sub-select I believe is a clue that there is more than one table row aggregated into each row of the sub-select.

Comment: @KevinBedell, you are absolutely right, I figured a subselect was needed, and just didn't think much when I actually wrote it. Your solution is the correct one.